# List the content of the Win32 device namespace

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, namespaces, device

From the microsoft-doku:

> The `"\\.\"` prefix will access the Win32 device namespace instead of
>   the Win32 file namespace. This is how access to physical disks and
>   volumes is accomplished directly, without going through the file
>   system, if the API supports this type of access. You can access many
>   devices other than disks this way (using the CreateFile and
>   DefineDosDevice functions, for example).
>
> For example, if you want to open the system's serial communications
>   port 1, you can use "COM1" in the call to the CreateFile function.
>   This works because COM1–COM9 are part of the reserved names in the NT
>   namespace, although using the `"\\.\"` prefix will also work with these
>   device names.

My Question is, what is available in this namespace. Is there a list of devices and where can I get it ?
(I think I did not understand this topic. When I hear device I think of some sort of file in a directory.)

EDIT:

Ok, I will answer my own question. There is a software called WinObj , with which one can see the information .

Comment: You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I will answer my own question. There is a software called WinObj , with which one can see the information .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `QueryDosDevice` Win32 API call to get all Win32 device names.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEVBUFSIZ (128 * 1024)      /* No recommended value - ~14K for me */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    wchar_t devicenames[DEVBUFSIZ]  = L"";
    int     error                   = 0;
    int     wchar_count             = 0;

    wchar_count = QueryDosDeviceW(
            NULL,       /* lpDeviceName - NULL gives all */
            devicenames,
            DEVBUFSIZ);
    if (wchar_count == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "QueryDosDeviceW failed with error code %d\n", error);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wchar_count; i++) {
        if (devicenames[i] == '\0')
            devicenames[i] = '\n';
    }
    wprintf(L"%s", devicenames);
    return 0;
}
```

As an aside, WinObj does not primarily list Win32 device names, it lists Windows NT object names. Though the Win32 device names can be found under the `GLOBAL??` node in WinObj.

See "More Information" in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100027